# Add global Authorization filter in ASP.NET Core 2.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-authorization

in my ConfigureServices i have created a policy based authorization

```
 services.AddAuthorization(options =>
 {
     options.AddPolicy("test", policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TestRequirement()));
 });
```

and registered the handler as below

```
services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, CustomAuthorizationHandler>();
```

but rather than applying authorization on top of all controller like this

```
[Authorize(Policy = "test")]
```

**Is there a way to apply authorize attribute globally like in MVC 5?**

I tried

```
services.AddMvc(config=>config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute("test")))
```

but I think something wrong here.

Answer (score 5):

You should first create a policy using the `AuthorizationPolicyBuilder` in ConfigureServices and then you can do the following:

```
services.AddMvc(config =>
{
    config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
});
```

Where policy is your test policy ...